# The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. Xcode using flutter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I am using flutter and xcode to deploy my app on my device, but everytime I try to install it on my device, I get the following Error

> The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.

I have tried

- removing all the certificates, Provisional profiles
- removing the apple id and signing in again
- different apple id
- checked the bundle ids

all of this has failed, also I am using a free developers account.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case it helped setting the Pods deployment target to the iOS Version I was running.
Was testing on an old Iphone 6 so I did the following:

1. Open project in Xcode
2. Go to Runner - General - Scroll to section Deployment Info and set Target iOS Version (in my case 12.4)
3. Go to Pods - (Project Pods not Targets) -> Info - set Deployment Target to same iOS Version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you are using a paid developer account, you can do the following steps:

- Open Xcode
- Open Settings and navigate to tab `Accounts`
- Select your Apple ID and appropriate team
- Click on `Manage Certificates`
- Click button `+` and wait for Xcode to do the job
- Run and build app again

Hope it helps!